# TV Show with alien conspiracy theorist, one character has "lightning" superpowers

Tags: story-identification, tv

For some reason I have this very distinct memory of watching a specific scene in an episode of a show when I was very young.
The main characters [there's two, a man and a woman] are talking to this guy who is like a hardcore believer/conspiracy theorist, and he has all this 'proof' of aliens and paranormal things tacked to his wall, and most of it is implied to most likely be junk, but one picture is actually the main guy [altho not distinctly recognisable as him, so the believer has no clue]
And in the photo there's lights and maybe lightning everywhere, so I assume the main guy has lightning powers, and I'm pretty sure he's an alien or something along those lines but I don't actually know.

I remember there was some concern because the believer had put his entire life into this, and the main characters wanted to help him, but he seemed to believe the "unknown" guy in the photo was at fault for something bad in his life, and they didn't want to reveal that it was actually the main guy, both because he seemed to hate the "Unknown" guy, and also because the powers were very much supposed to be a secret.

I just know I sometimes randomly remember that scene and really want to know what show it is so I can watch it and finally put it all into context!

It was on TV when I was super young so it may have aired in the late 90s or early 2000s
But it could have been a rerun so idk;;;;;

Comment: There is actually an [episode of the X-Files](http://x-files.wikia.com/wiki/D.P.O.) concerning a young man with lightning powers...

Comment: @TrishLing I actually thought it could have been an X-Files episode for a long time when I was younger, but I've watched every episode, including that one, and it isn't.
Thanks for trying to help tho!

Comment: Please describe the physical appearance of the two main characters (the man & woman) - that will help a great deal.

Comment: @Omegacron I remember that they were both white and had darker hair, but to be honest I can't remember how they looked past that. I thought it might have been an X-files episode when I was younger, but I've watched X-files and now know that isn't the case.

Comment: Did the woman look like (a young) Shiri Appleby or Katherine Heigl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Mutant X*, Season 3 Episode 12, "[Conspiracy Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mutant_X_episodes#Season_3_.282003.E2.80.9304.29)" has Brennan, the electricity-wielding mutant, deal with a conspiracy theorist obsessed with aliens.

> Brennan and Shalimar investigate a mystery of a secret group working while they find a person who thinks that Mutants are aliens and everything including GSA, Genomex and Adam Kane is a conspiracy meanwhile Lexa struggles to make a decision of continuing as a part of Mutant X or leaving it since her deal with Dominion of finding her brother is over.

Comment: That's it!!Oh my god, as soon as I saw the conspiracy guy it clicked, that's him!! Thank you, this has literally been bugging me on and off for years!

Comment: Glad I could help. I remembered the electric guy and then searched for whether they'd dealt with aliens or conspiracy theorists.